# Display image and description from plugin(redux) which is an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have this array which is inside the variable `$cablecar_nhp`. When I `var_dump()` the variable it give me this.

```
array(3) { 
    ["last_tab"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["media"]=> array(5) { 
        ["url"]=> string(65) "http://sample.com/wp_cablecar/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Koala.jpg" 
        ["id"]=> string(2) "84" 
        ["height"]=> string(3) "768" 
        ["width"]=> string(4) "1024" 
        ["thumbnail"]=> string(72) "http://sample.com/wp_cablecar/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Koala-120x95.jpg"
    }
    ["REDUX_imported"]=> bool(false)
}
```

What i want to do is to get and display the image. Can anybody help me ? I am working on Wordpress.

Comment: there are two images, both can be displayed using foreach loop. what did you try ?

Comment: i have tried this code but gives me different image. i know its not as simply as this but i'm not good in manipulating array. i just want to display the first image first.
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($cablecar_nhp); ?>

Comment: what is result if you use print_r($cablecar_nhp);

Comment: it displays array also like the one with var_dump

Comment: okay i got the answer.

since its a two dimensional array. it should be done like this

<a href='".$cablecar_nhp['media']['url']."'  id= '".$cablecar_nhp['media']['id']."'>;
<img src='".$cablecar_nhp['media']['thumbnail']."' height='".$cablecar_nhp['media']['height.']."' width='".$cablecar_nhp['media']['width']."' >;
</a>;

Thanks Guys for helping and giving idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the core devs of Redux. You can access your variable in question by expanding on what Valery said:

```
echo '<imv src="'.$cablecar_nhp['media']['url'].'">';
```

Or, do what pr1nc3 suggests above.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```
echo '<img src = "'. $cablecar_nhp['url'] .'">';
```

Comment: the image is still not displayed but the container is filled up with something but not the image.

Comment: oh, i dissmised that ts a two dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

```
extract($cablecar_nhp['media']);
<a href="$url" id="$id"> <img src="$thumbnail" height="$height" width="$width" > </a>
```

Comment: this doesnt display the image also